# JQuery Form Submission with enter key AJAX API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've tried various solutions, but none are suitable for my particular case!
How can I make it so that when the user presses 'Enter' the form submits & searches.
I also want to try and remove the JavaScript from the HTML document, and move it to the ajax.js document & select it.
I'm unsure of the correct syntax to do so.
I am using rotten tomatoes API with AJAX by the way.

**search.php**

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="GET"><h3>Search for a movie here:</h3><br> 
    <input type="text" id="inputbox" value="">&nbsp;
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Go!" onClick="filmlist(this.form)">
        </form>
```

**ajax.js**

```
function filmlist (form) {
$('#films table').empty(); //removes previous search results before adding the new ones.

var apikey = "frceg2d5djxezaedgm3qq94h";
var baseUrl = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0";
var moviesSearchUrl = baseUrl + '/movies.json?apikey=' + apikey;
var query = form.inputbox.value;  //uses the value from the input box as the query search



  // sends the query
  $.ajax({
    url: moviesSearchUrl + '&q=' + encodeURI(query),
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: searchCallback
  });


// receives the results

function searchCallback(data) {
 $('#films table').append('Found ' + data.total + ' results for ' + query);
 var movies = data.movies;
 $.each(movies, function(index, movie) {
    $('#films table').append('<tr><td width="70" rowspan="2"><a href="' + movie.links.alternate +
    '" title="Click here to view film information for ' + movie.title + '."><img class="ajaximage" src="'
    + movie.posters.thumbnail + '" /></a></td><td class="ajaxfilmlisttitle"><h3><a href="' + movie.links.alternate +
    '" title="Click here to view film information for ' + movie.title + '.">' + movie.title + '</a></h3>Release year: '
    + movie.year + '</td></tr><tr><td class="ajaxfilmlistinfo">Audience Score: ' + movie.ratings.audience_score +
    '%<br>' + 'Cinema Release Date: ' + movie.release_dates.theater +
    '<br>Runtime: ' + movie.runtime + ' minutes</td></tr>');
 });
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "remove the JavaScript from the HTML document, and move it to the ajax.js document & select it"?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: moviesSearchUrl + '&q=' + encodeURI(query),
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: searchCallback
    });
    return false;
});
```

or you can just `return false` at the end of your filmlist function.

Answer (score -1):

You can detect an enter keypress in the #inputbox element with the following jQuery code:

```
$('#inputbox').keyup(function(e) 
{
    if(e.keyCode == 13) 
    {
        //do your stuff
    }
});
```

You can also use `$('#inputbox').change()` to directly load movies when the user is typing.

Do not forget that some old or mobile browser do not have JavaScript support. Always build an server side solution as fallback.